# How do I capture scrolling input on a webpage WITHOUT having a page actually scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, input, scroll

I'm creating a spectrum color picker (where it shows all the colors in a gradient) and I currently only have hue on the y axis and lightness (brightness) on the x axis. I want to make scrolling change the saturation of the color, as there isn't much room to add a slider because I have the whole page as the picker.

color picker html and css (nothing wrong here):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HTML Colour Picker</title>
    <style>
        html {height: 100%; font-family: monospace;}
        p {margin: 0px;}
        body {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          position: relative;
          background: linear-gradient(to left, black, transparent, white), linear-gradient(#f00, #ff0, #0f0, #0ff, #00f, #f0f, #f00);
        }
        svg {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; left: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onmousemove="mousemove(event)" onclick="toggle()" onload>
    <input type="color">
    <p id="pos">pos: move the cursor to start</p>
    <p id="rgb">red: move the cursor to start</p>
    <p id="hsl">red: move the cursor to start</p>
    <p id="hex">hex: move the cursor to start</p>

    <svg width="16px" height="16px">
        <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" fill="#fff6" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    </svg>

    <script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon googling, the only results I found were ones that involve the page actually scrolling. I also tried looking for ways to read how far the user has scrolled on the page so I could let the page scroll, keep the content centered and hide the scroll bar, but I still can't find anything (probably because I'm just bad at researching).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `wheel` event and `preventDefault`

```js
scrollable.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(event.deltaY)
})
```

```css
#scrollable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable">scroll me</div>
```